# Dynamically Render Nav's Sub Menu Under Appropriate Main Menu Item

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm attempting to dynamically set nav menu items and sub menu items via React Props. I am able to iterate using `.map` and get the main list items `navItems.label` to appear.

I am also able to get sub menu items to appear, however I cannot separate the two sub menus. For instance, currently, I can only iterate through one sub menu or the other `subItems[0]` or `subItems[1]`. Of course this will render the same items twice.

I feel like I'm missing a bit of logic in order to render appropriate sub items relative to each object.

JSX:

```
const Nav = ({ navItems }) => {

const subItems = navItems.map(el => el.subMenu)

return (
  {navItems.map(item => (
    <li>
      <a href="#">{item.label}</a>
      <ul>
        {subItems[0].map(subItem => (
            <li>{subItem.item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ))}
)

}
```

Props getting passed in:

```
<Nav
        navItems={[
          {
            label: "About",
            subMenu: [
              {
                id: 1,
                item: "About Sub Item 1",
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                item: "About Sub Item 2",
              },
              {
                id: 3,
                item: "About Sub Item 3",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            label: "Blog",
            subMenu: [
              {
                id: 1,
                item: "Blog Sub Item 1",
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                item: "Blog Sub Item 2",
              },
              {
                id: 3,
                item: "Blog Sub Item 3",
              },
            ],
          },
        ]}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `.map` method's index argument, and use that to populate appropriate sub Menu array.

```
{navItems.map((item, index) => (
    <li>
      <a href="#">{item.label}</a>
      <ul>
        {subItems[index].map(subItem => (
            <li>{subItem.item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ))}
```